# problema al concatenar variable en SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una query en SQL donde intento concatenar un variable que evaluo con un if, pero el problema que tengo es que cuando entra a
la opción N esa cadena no la esta concatenando en el SELECT ya que no me esta regresando resultados (si debe regresar rows), cuando coloco la opción M
si me regresa resultados, imprimo la variable @stringSQL y si esta trayendo el valor según la opción en el caso de M si me regresa lo que contiene la variable
@stringSQL, así como estoy concatenado la variable

```html
Declare @stringSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
IF @Operacion = 'N' 
    BEGIN
        SET @stringSQL=' AND ACTIVO=1 '
        SELECT @stringSQL
    END
    ELSE IF @Operacion = 'M' OR @Operacion='C'
    BEGIN
        SET @stringSQL=''
        SELECT @stringSQL
    END
  
  SELECT CLV_TRABAJO,(TRABAJO + ' - ' + DESCRIPCION) AS DESCRIPCION 
                    FROM TRABAJOS 
                    WHERE CLV_TIPSER=@CLV_TIPSER AND TIPO='Q' + @stringSQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede agregar código dinámico a una sentencia estática. Lo único que estás haciendo es comparar la columna `TIPO` con el valor `'Q AND ACTIVO=1 '`.

Claro que se puede utilizar código dinámico para generar toda la instrucción y ejecutarla, pero en este caso solo es necesario utilizar un poco de lógica para establecer las condiciones.

```
SELECT CLV_TRABAJO,
        (TRABAJO + ' - ' + DESCRIPCION) AS DESCRIPCION 
FROM TRABAJOS 
WHERE CLV_TIPSER = @CLV_TIPSER 
AND TIPO = 'Q' 
AND (ACTIVO = 1 OR ISNULL( @Operacion, '') <> 'N');
```

La función ISNULL podría evitarse si el valor de @Operacion nunca será nulo.

**Explicación de como trabaja la condición:**

La condición se puede probar con una tabla de verdad de la disyunción (en otras palabras, que pasa con los distintos resultados de dos comparaciones unidas por OR)

| ACTIVO = 1 | @Operacion <> 'N' | ACTIVO = 1 or @Operacion <> 'N' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V | V | V |
| F | V | V |
| V | F | V |
| F | F | F |

En este caso, si @Operacion es distinto a 'N' (la condición regresa verdadero), no importa el valor de ACTIVO y es como si no estuviera esa condición. Cuando @Operacion es igual a 'N' (o sea que no es diferente y la condición regresa falso) entonces requiere que ACTIVO sea igual a 1.

Comment: si funciono pero no entendí la condición que agregaste de AND (ACTIVO=1 OR ISNULL... me podrias ayudar a comprender tu condicion?

Comment: Agregué una explicación a la respuesta. Espero que sea suficiente. Por eso había que poner atención en las cláses de lógica de la escuela.

Comment: Gracias..., no había visualizado la condición de la forma que explicaste